# How to transition AngularJS 1.8.x. -> Angular CLI version 11.2.3?

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-cli

I’m trying to update the angular version for a web app. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: No. There is no simple way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

That is a rewrite. AngularJs is a different framework than Angular TypeScript.  There is a hybrid mode to run the two side by side while upgrading but it is not ideal.

https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Your best path is a complete rewrite.